# Notice: Undefined index: on WooCommerce Loop

Tags: php, woocommerce

Getting the following error on a [woocommerce shop](http://www.charmaynemakeup.com/product-category/classic-man/):

> Notice: Undefined index: columns in
>   /hermes/bosweb26a/b1953/ipw.felix1968/public_html/wp-content/themes/charmaynemakeup/woocommerce/loop/loop-start.php
>   on line 12

I searched around and found `isset` is the way forward. Kindly can someone point me how to address this.

Answer (score 2):

Notice is not an error. You can turn it off in wp-config.php with

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );
```

However that will not repair your code (you should have debug false on production anyways). Undefined index means that you are trying to access index of array which is not available.
Before running that line of code, ask if is set.

```
if( isset( $array( 'column' ) ) )
    echo $array( 'column' );
```